# Visualforce and CSS - nothing

Tags: visualforce, css

I can't get any CSS to work at all. Am I missing something extremely obvious?

EDITED to include URLfor

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" >
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.cssSampleGREEN)}"/>

    <h1>test content for color output</h1>
</apex:page>
```

If I have a static resource called cssSampleGREEN which is the COMPLEX CSS code

```
<style type="text/css">
h1
{
    color:#00cdcd;
}
```

I should at least have green output to my h1 text but that does not happen, I just get the below. What is my error?

[image]

Comment: The code looks ok to me. Try removing both sidebar and standardStyleSheets from apex page definition. Keep showheader as false.

Comment: If its a zip file then use URLFOR function to reference your static resource.

Comment: I have made false both sidebar, header, and standardstylesheets

Comment: I m saying to keep only showheader as false and remove the other two attributes

Comment: Keep your page definition as you have it. It's fine and if you remove `useStandardStylesheets="false"` your css may get overridden.

Comment: Also, to prevent any other errors, make sure the name of the zipped CSS file is exactly the same name and the name of the static resource. ie, the file should be called cssSampleGREEN and so should the static resource in the web upload interface.

Comment: Your css file definition has no closing tag - make sure it's closed properly.

Comment: So, any luck there?

Comment: No, I can only get result when I use the SF provided zip example and use this line: <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.stylesSF, 'styles.css')}" />  Very unclear why I can't even get a basic CSS to do anything

Comment: Close tags? i don't know how to close, don't see any close tags in the samples i am building from

Comment: I don't know why the simple CSS isn't doing anything. I can get more complicated CSS from others to work, but not all. I was hoping to be able to test my own and found this odd inability to get the simplest to work.

Answer (score 7):

It's fine - just take the `<style>` tags out of stylesheet.

Static resource like this :-)

```
h1
{
    color: #00cdcd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated with list of what you need to do:

- Use `URLFOR()`
- Remove your CSS style tag in your CSS file
- Name the Resource file the same as your css filename to simplify, ie, Resource is called `mystyles` and CSS file is called `mystyles.css`
- `URLFOR()` syntax should be like this:
  `<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.mystyles, 'mystyles.css')}"/>`
- Set cache control to "Public"
- Ensure you are setting `standardStylesheets="false"`

Your CSS file should look like this (note no close tag - thanks mattandneil, missed that):

```
h1{
    color:#00cdcd;
}
```

You (were) not actually using `URLFOR()` in your stylesheet code.
Add that, using the syntax described [here](http://salesforcesource.blogspot.co.nz/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html). You'll see that in many cases, you need a `target` and an `id` param (it would appear that you need these all the time, but this does not seem to be true).

I noticed that didn't close your style tag in the css file. You should close this because it could break things in the page.

If this doesn't work, inspect your page (right click and most browsers will give you the option to "inspect" the element you click on) and you should see the broken link as a load resource error on the page.

Perhaps you have the css in a folder that you zipped up to upload as a static resource. If it's in a folder, you'd refer to it like this:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.your_zipped_folder, 'your_zipped_folder/your_css.css')}"/>
```

Finally, make sure cache control on the static resource is set to public.

Comment: It's not zipped. So this should work? <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.cssSampleGREEN)}"/> - this URLFOR element is not referenced in this page https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_styling_custom.htm

Comment: Did you make sure cache control was set to public when you saved the resource?

Comment: Yes, use URLFOR.

Comment: it is set to public now

Comment: Hah - I just noticed, you don't actually have URLFOR there! Put it in and you should be golden - leave everything else the same. :)